# distance between two longitude and latitude

Tags: sql-server-2008

How should I write query for this?
Consider P1(a, b)  and P2(c, d) to be two points on a 2D plane.

- a happens to equal the minimum value in Northern Latitude (LAT_N in
  STATION).
- b happens to equal the maximum value in Northern Latitude
  (LAT_N in STATION)
- c happens to equal the minimum value in Western
  Longitude (LONG_W in STATION)
- d happens to equal the maximum value
  in Western Longitude (LONG_W in STATION)

Query the Manhattan Distance between points P1 and P2 and round it to a scale of 4 decimal places.

```
Table STATION(ID number, CITY varchar2(21), STATE varchar2(2), LAT_N number, LONG_W number)
```

this is my try but returns NULL

```
select
    2 * 3961 * asin(power(sqrt((sin(radians(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N)) / 2) )) , 2 ) + cos(radians(MAX(LAT_N))) * cos(radians(MIN(LAT_N))) * power(sqrt((sin(radians(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)) / 2) )) , 2 )) as distance from station where city like 'manhattan';
```

Answer (score 4):

For MySQL,

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)),4) FROM STATION
```

Comment: note I'm no SQL expert but if you write on HackerRank MAX (LAT_N) instead of MAX(LAT_N) -basically adding a space) it will say the function MAX doesn't exist

Comment: It's still showing the wrong answer the answer came up as 259.68590000  I tried my own logic too which is                                                                                                     SELECT ROUND(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N) + MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W), 4) 
FROM STATION;           any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server you can use the following query:

```
SELECT convert(decimal(10,4),ABS(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W))) FROM STATION
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this maths formula to get the straight distance between two points:

```
Distance = squarerootof((x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Manhattan Distance ([Taxicab Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry))

Manhattan Distance between points P1(a,b) and P2(c,d)= |a-c|+|b-d|

```
--a= min(LAT_N)
--b= max(LAT_N)
--c= min(LONG_W)
--d= max(LONG_w)
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N) - MIN(LONG_W)),4) + ROUND(ABS(MAX(LAT_N) - MAX(LONG_W)),4) FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(abs(min(lat_n)- max(lat_n)) + abs(min(long_w)- max(long_w)),4) from  station;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @a float, @b float, @c float, @d float;
      SET @a =(select LAT_N from station where LAT_N = (select min(LAT_N) from station) )
      SET @b =(select LONG_W from station where LONG_W =(Select min(LONG_W) from station) )
      SET @c= (select LAT_N from station where LAT_N = (select max(LAT_N) from station) )
      SET @d= (select LONG_W from station where LONG_W = (select max(LONG_W) from station) ) 
select cast(ROUND((abs(@a -@c)+ abs(@b - @d)),4) as decimal(12,4))
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be good if you could provide some non-code text with your answer, perhaps explaining how it works or what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of doing this problem is
Using mathematics function [ *Dis. = sqrt((x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2)* ], try:
**for sql server:**

```
select format(abs(min(LAT_N)-max(LAT_N))+abs(min(long_w)-max(long_w)),'.####') from station;
```

or

```
select format(sqrt(square(min(LAT_N)-max(LAT_N))+square(min(long_w)-max(long_w))),'.####') from station;
```

**for SQL:**

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W)), 4) FROM STATION;
```

for simplicity to understand:

```
select 
  round(
    abs(
      min(lat_n)- max(lat_n)
    ) + abs(
      min(long_w)- max(long_w)
    ), 4
  ) 
from 
  station;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: a=MIN(LAT_N) c=MAX(LAT_N) b=MIN(LONG_W) d=MAX(LONG_W)

#Query for obtaining Manhattan distance is:

```
    SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N))+ABS(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W)),4) FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below using Oracle.

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W) - MAX(LONG_W)) , 4)
FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question, they are asking to find *Manhattan Distance* but you are trying to find **Euclidean distance** between two points. Both of them are different

**Manhattan Distance:**
|X1 - X2| + |Y1 - Y2|

**Euclidean Distance:**
sqrt((X2−X1)^2+(Y2 −Y1)^2)

```sql
select Format(ABS(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W)),'.####') from STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance between two points. Both of them are different.

**Manhattan Distance:**

```
|X1 - X2| + |Y1 - Y2|

select round((max(lat_n)-min(lat_n))+(max(long_w)-min(long_w)),4)
from station
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the compiler seems to ignore the `ROUND()` function and still output all the decimal places. I used the `SUBSTR()` function to work around this bug. So the query would look like:

```
select substr((ABS(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N)) + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W))), 1, 8) FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one for MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE points (
a DECIMAL(10,4),
b DECIMAL(10,4),
c DECIMAL(10,4),
d DECIMAL(10,4));

INSERT INTO points VALUE ((SELECT MIN(lat_n) FROM station),
  (SELECT MIN(long_w) FROM station),
    (SELECT MAX(lat_n) FROM station),
    (SELECT MAX(long_w) FROM station));
  

SELECT ROUND((c - a) + (d - b),4) FROM points;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(abs(max(lat_n )-min(lat_n)) + abs(max(long_w)-min(long_w)),4)
    from station
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one,

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N) + MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W), 4) FROM STATION
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast((round((max(lat_n)-min(lat_n)),4)) as decimal (10,4))+ cast(round((max(long_w)-min(long_w)),4) as decimal(10,4)) from station;
```

Comment: This one works for me. Using just round() does not

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select round( ABS(max(LAT_N)-min(LAT_N)) +
ABS(max(LONG_W)-min(LONG_W)),4 ) FROM STATION
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

-- a = min(lat_n); b = min(long_w) ; c= max(lat_n) ; d= max(long_w)
-- Manhattan Distance between points P1(a,b) and P2(c,d)= |c-a|+|d-b|

select round(abs(max(lat_n )-min(lat_n)) + abs(max(long_w)-min(long_w)),4)
from station

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(round(abs(Min(LAT_N) - Max(LAT_N)),4) + round(abs(Min(LONG_W) - Max(LONG_W)),4) as decimal(10,4)) from station;
```

try this query ,it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
select round((max(LAT_N) - min(LAT_N)) + (max(LONG_W) - min(LONG_W)),4) from station
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for MS SQL Server.

```
select cast(ABS(min(LAT_N) - max(LAT_N)) + 
ABS(min(LONG_W) - max(LONG_W)) as decimal (30,4))
from STATION enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

Manhattan distance

Definition: The distance between two points measured along axes at right angles. In a plane with p1 at (x1, y1) and p2 at (x2, y2), it is |x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|.

In the problem `x1` is `min(lat_n)` and `x2` is `max(lat_n)`, similarly `y1` will be `min(long_w)` and `y2` will be `max(long_w)`. Hence the query to perform this in MySQL is;

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W)),4) FROM STATION;
```

Comment: Please always disclose the source of the content you copy from elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

For MS SQL server logic

To find Manhattan distance between 2 points: P1(A,B) AND P2(C,D)

Formula : (C-A) + (D-B)

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N) + MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) 
FROM STATION
```

If you use the Round function, it will show you the wrong answer because the question asks for 4 decimal places only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).