# SQL - Agg Func Manhattan Distance

Tags: mysql, sql

---

SO Link doesn't answer the question. I can't figure out how to solve this query on Hackerspace. None of the solutions online seem to be working. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Consider P1(a,b) and P2(c,d) to be two points on a 2D plane.

a happens to equal the minimum value in Northern Latitude (LAT_N in STATION).

b happens to equal the minimum value in Western Longitude (LONG_W in STATION).

c happens to equal the maximum value in Northern Latitude (LAT_N in STATION).

d happens to equal the maximum value in Western Longitude (LONG_W in STATION).

Query the Manhattan Distance between points  and  and round it to a scale of  decimal places.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

**STATION Table**

1. ID | Number
2. City | VarChar2(21)
3. State | VarChar2(2)
4. LAT_N | Number
5. LONG_W | Number

Database: MySQL

Source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-18/problem

Link: [distance between two longitude and latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867808/distance-between-two-longitude-and-latitude) (Tried, but none of the answers provided work.)

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(Station.LAT_N) - MIN(Station.LONG_W)) + ABS(MAX(Station.LAT_N) - MAX(Station.Long_W)), 4) 
FROM Station;
```

Comment: Manhattan distance assumes a flat plane, which is a reasonable approximation over short distances. It doesn't work for spherical coordinates over long distances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula for manhattan distance is | a - c| + | b - d| where  a and b are min lat and long and c and d are max lat and long respectively.

```
select 
  round(
    abs(
      min(lat_n)- max(lat_n)
    ) + abs(
      min(long_w)- max(long_w)
    ), 4
  ) 
from 
  station;
```

I got 25 hakker points! so can I get 25 points from you?

Comment: Awarded you the answer because you provided the updated formula. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for that hackerrank site. it is a good place to practice skills.

Comment: You have messed up with max and min. They are needed to be interchanged

Comment: Google about abs (absolute value) and you will be enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

Without just writing the answer:  you need to calculate the horizontal difference between the min and max longitude, and add the vertical difference between the min and max latitude.

Your code does something a bit different. If you update your code accordingly, then the rest is OK and will be marked as correct by hackerrank.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing latitude and longitude when instead you need to compare latitude with latitude and longitude with longitude. The Manhattan distance between `(1,3)` and `(2,4)` is `|1-2|+|3-4|`, not `|1-4|+|2-3|`.

It should also be pointed out that since you're taking the min and max of the same range, you don't actually need the absolute value function. `round(max(x)-min(x)+max(y)-min(y), 4)` works perfectly well - and is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

My answer for MS SQL

```
SELECT CAST(
ABS(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N)) + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)) 
AS DECIMAL(20, 4)) 
FROM STATION
```

Comment: Kindly add more details to your answer, explanations on how your code works and how this address the OP's question would be a great help not just for the asker but also for the future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select round((max(lat_n)-min(lat_n)),4)+round((max(long_w)-min(long_w)),4)
from station;
```

As we will get result from diff of max and min we don't need abs.
The above code works for [Sql Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-18/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ROUND(ABS(MAX(Station.LAT_N) - MIN(Station.LONG_W)) + ABS(MIN(Station.LAT_N) - MAX(Station.Long_W)), 4)
FROM Station;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoGrZ.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for joining Stack Overflow. Your answer to the question is a duplicate of previously provided answers. Please continue to try to help, but please also try to not duplicate other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for `MS SQL` -

```
SELECT CAST(ABS(MIN(lat_n) - MAX(lat_n)) + ABS(MIN(long_w) - MAX(long_w)) as decimal(10,4))
FROM station
```

OR

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(a - c) + ABS(b - d), decimal_places) AS Manhattan_Distance
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MIN(lat_n) AS a,
    MIN(long_w) AS b,
    MAX(lat_n) AS c,
    MAX(long_w) AS d
  FROM station
) subquery;
```

In both ways you will get `259.6859`

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER FOR SQL-SERVER:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(
        CAST(ROUND(ABS(A - C) + ABS(B - D),4) AS VARCHAR(20)),
        1,
        charindex('.',CAST(ROUND(ABS(A - C) + ABS(B - D),4) AS VARCHAR(20)))+4
    )
FROM (    
    SELECT
        MIN(LAT_N) AS A,
        MIN(LONG_W) AS B,
        MAX(LAT_N) AS C,
        MAX(LONG_W) AS D
    FROM STATION
) SBQRY;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since given a = MIN(LAT_N), c = MAX(LAT_N), b = MIN(LONG_W) and d = MAX(LONG_W)
> **Manhattan Distance = |a-c| + |b-d|**
> Given that round the answer a scale of 4 decimal places, we use the **ROUND** query

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N)) + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)), 4)
FROM STATION
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).